# Is it possible to implement Firebase Dynamic Links on Huawei devices?

Tags: android, firebase, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I created android application which is using dynamic links

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context)
Firebase.dynamicLinks
  .getDynamicLink(intent)
  .addOnSuccessListener(context) { successFunction(it) }
  .addOnFailureListener(context) { failureFunction(it) }

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links-ktx:19.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.3.0'
```

I found tutorial to proxy firebase-analytics to Huawei device by HMS Core:
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/Tools-Guides/30935655
but there's no information at all about firebase-dynamic-links

Is there any possibility to use Firebase Dynamic Links on the newest Huawei devices ?

Comment: I am not sure, but I doubt it seeing that firebase is owned by google

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pure Huawei devices(Huawei P40) you can not use Firebase Dynamic Links, instead of Firebase Dynamic Link you can use ["App Linking"](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction) or third [party kits](https://branch.io/) on Huawei devices.
They have sample [code](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Examples/agc-applinking-samplecode) also.

Answer (score 2):

As of date (20 Oct 2020), Firebase doesn't support link to Huawei App gallery since Firebase depends on Google Play services which is restricted on latest Huawei devices.

On the other hand, Huawei App Linking service supports HMS (Huawei), GMS (Google) and also iOS platform. iOS support is currently in Beta though, so we should expect its final version soon.

All this means that Huawei App Links has more coverage (GMS, HMS, iOS) as compared to Firebase Dynamic Links (just GMS and iOS).

Adding further, [branch.io](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/android-basic-integration) (3rd part provider, mentioned in another answer too) supports all these platforms - GMS, HMS, iOS.

Answer (score 1):

No. Officially Firebase is dependent on Google Play Services. You should not expect any Firebase service to work in phones that have no Google Play Services. Even if some Firebase services do actually work currently they can stop working at any time without prior notice and break your app.

In my opinion you should treat all Firebase services as not working on phones with no Google Play Services. Trying to find hacks and workarounds will only lead to hard to debug problems later on.

Answer (score 0):

On Huawei mobile phones without GMS, developers can try to use app linking to achieve the same functions：
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Dynamic Links cannot work on phones without GMS.

GMS will be called for redirecting to the link. So if there is no GMS, redirection to the link cannot be processed.

You can use [App Linking](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/agc-applinking-introduction) on Huawei devices.

Answer (score -3):

I am very late to answer this, but i got this issue today while developing the Ionic application using firebase dynamic links.
As Huawei devices probably do not support the google-services. So I just downloaded the Google Play Store and dynamic apps are working perfectly/

> Download Google Play Store (This will help in working with Google services and firebase Dynamic link will work perfectly).

Comment: You can't make your users download an unofficial version of Google Play Services to install it on their devices.

Comment: But to add Google service to any device. We want have Google Play and its supporting packages.